# How to create GraphServiceClient using AuthorizationCodeCredential?

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am building a webapi app which fetches the files and directories from any organization. Hence I decided to use Authorization Code flow to fetch the access token. I am using Microsoft.Graph nuget package. I am using `AuthorizationCodeCredential` class to create the `GraphServiceClient`. Once I created the client object I don't want to lose it, I want to reuse the same client without create another new object which requires `authorizationCode`. How do I go about it?

```
            var authorizationCode = "AUTH_CODE";
            var scopes = new[]
            {
                "User.Read", "User.Read.All", "User.ReadBasic.All", "User.ReadWrite",
                "User.ReadWrite.All",
                "Files.Read", "Files.Read.All", "Files.ReadWrite", "Files.ReadWrite.All",
                "Directory.Read.All", "Directory.Read.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All"
            };
            var options = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                RedirectUri = new Uri(_redirectUri)
            };

            var authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
                _tenantId, _clientId, _clientSecret, authorizationCode, options);
            _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authCodeCredential, scopes);
            return _graphClient;
```

I tried following what's written in the documentation [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#authorization-code-provider:%7E:text=azure%2Didentity%20library.-,Authorization%20code%20provider,-The%20authorization%20code) I am able to create a graph client but i don't want to generate AUTH_CODE everytime but at the same time I want to serve multiple tenants. Is there a way better way to do it?
Am I using a wrong flow?

Comment: You are using OAUTH2 which is a two step authentication.  Step one is to request a token/cookie.  Set two is to perform a query using the token.  You can use the same token multiple times without performing step one multiple times.  Cookies have a timeout before they expired.  So as long as the cookie doesn't expire you can reuse the cookie.